How to detect undefined symbols in shared libraries or objects?
My Linux distribution (openSUSE Slowroll) accidentally shipped some incompatible libraries recently due to its experimental nature, lacking adequate automated testing using openQA, that caused the desktop environment and other programs like flatpak to crash on startup.
The relevant errors:
Oct 10 09:05:09 suse-pc gnome-shell[2946]: JS ERROR: GLib.Error g-invoke-error-quark: Could not locate g_settings_bind_with_mapping_closures: 'g_settings_bind_with_mapping_closures': /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_settings_bind_with_mapping_closures
Oct 14 03:07:36 suse-pc atomic-update[342567]: flatpak: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_sort_array

I have a simple program I use to perform atomic updates, so I was wondering if there was a way to detect these undefined symbols in shared libraries/objects, so the faulty update can be discarded instead of being applied.
Thanks!

EDIT 1:
I found an easy way to detect incompatible libraries was to print the version string for the program being tested:
pavin@suse-laptop:~/Downloads> gnome-control-center --version
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgoa-backend-1.0.so.2: undefined symbol: adw_button_row_get_type, version LIBADWAITA_1_0

As @MarcusMüller said in the comments, this may not work always. So it is necessary to perform the check for a list of all essential programs you need.

in this case: yes, that might have been possible with an intense use of nm and objdump, but in general, you can't know which symbols a program tries to find in a shared library until it does – at runtime. So, you would need to execute all possible code  paths in all possible programs. Not feasible! The problem here is not missing QA, the problem here seems to be that someone built flatpak against glib >= 2.82.0, using features that were introduced in glib 2.82.0, but did not mark that version of glib a minimum version. Or, you have explicitly taken steps not to update glib when you updated

flatpak, which I guess is something you wouldn't think about coming from a "normal" release cycle OS to a rolling release distro such as slowroll. I still consider it a bug on slowroll's side that this is possible at all. So, the solution here is not really testing, it's applying OpenSuse Leap's existing tooling for requiring dependency updates to a rolling distro. (I'm surprised this didn't happen here, I'd expect that kind of stability from OpenSuse)

@MarcusMüller Thanks, could you please elaborate on how to use nm and objdump to detect undefined symbols? I'm thinking of doing that if possible plus checking the version of the major programs like gnome-shell, flatpak, etc. as a simple check to see if there are issues. Usually interpreted programs in perl and python are quick to complain if a dependency is missing or incompatible, so I'm guessing it should work similar in compiled programs?

For example, I checked deleting a shared library needed by zypper (the package manager) and it didn't even print the version string: https://paste.opensuse.org/pastes/5d93f2b1ce6d
I'm hoping it would similarly complain when encountering an incompatible library instead of a missing one!

it definitely won't. Because, "incompatible" is a runtime emergent property of things, not something checked at "rest", aside from actual missing symbols.

You can see how to print undefined but used symbols if these are declared in a static manner (again, not the case, in general!!!) using man nm; there's a lot of options to control which symbols to print, and I can't really write a book on static and dynamic linking here to help you build a at-rest-best-effort-dynamic-linking-resolver-checker.
